# ReactJS - '.env' file not works as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I added a `.env` file with my project as :
`NODE_PATH=src/` - so later on I import the components like:

```
import Subtitle from "Components/Subtitle";
```

instead of regular approach as `import Subtitle from "./Components/Subtitle";` since `.env` added the path. 
But still not works as expected.

What is the mistake here i do?
How to define the base path, if this is wrong?
Any one help me here?

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zz2kn9pjpm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a typo. Rename `.evn` to `.env`.
2. Ensure that you don't have any spaces in `.env` file. In your case it should be `NODE_PATH=src/`.

And here's forked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/01nrxn77xn)